# Using Neo4j with React JS

Tags: neo4j, reactjs

Can we use graph database neo4j with react js? If not so is there any alternate option for including graph database in react JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr;**

Yes, you can!

---

You are mixing two different technologies together. Neo4j is graph database and React.js is framework for front-end.

You can connect to Neo4j from JavaScript - http://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/

Comment: the second answer is more relevant

Answer (score 9):

Easily, all you need is `neo4j-driver`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver

Here is the most simplistic usage:

neo4j.js

```
//import { v1 as neo4j } from 'neo4j-driver'
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1

const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost', neo4j.auth.basic('username', 'password'))

const session = driver.session()

session
    .run(`
        MATCH (n:Node)
        RETURN n AS someName
    `)
    .then((results) => {
        results.records.forEach((record) => console.log(record.get('someName')))
        session.close()
        driver.close()
    })
```

It is best practice to close the session always after you get the data. It is inexpensive and lightweight.

It is best practice to only close the driver session once your program is done (like Mongo DB). You will see extreme errors if you close the driver at a bad time, which is incredibly important to note if you are beginner. You will see errors like 'connection to server closed', etc. In async code, for example, if you run a query and close the driver before the results are parsed, you will have a bad time.

You can see in my example that I close the driver after, but only to illustrate proper cleanup. If you run this code in a standalone JS file to test, you will see node.js hangs after the query and you need to press CTRL + C to exit. Adding `driver.close()` fixes that. Normally, the driver is not closed until the program exits/crashes, which is never in a Backend API, and not until the user logs out in the Frontend.

Knowing this now, you are off to a great start.

Remember, `session.close()` immediately every time, and be careful with the `driver.close()`.

You could put this code in a React component or action creator easily and render the data.

**You will find it no different than hooking up and working with Axios.**

You can run statements in a transaction also, which is beneficial for writelocking affected nodes. You should research that thoroughly first, but transaction flow is like this:

```
const session = driver.session()
const tx = session.beginTransaction()

tx
    .run(query)
    .then(// same as normal)
    .catch(// errors)

// the difference is you can chain multiple transactions:

const tx1 = await tx.run().then()

// use results

const tx2 = await tx.run().then()

// then, once you are ready to commit the changes:


if (results.good !== true) {
    tx.rollback()
    session.close()
    throw error
}

await tx.commit()
session.close()

const finalResults = { tx1, tx2 }
return finalResults

// in my experience, you have to await tx.commit
// in async/await syntax conditions, otherwise it may not commit properly
// that operation is not instant
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting topic. I am using the driver in a React App and recently experienced some issues. I am closing the session every time a lifecycle hook completes like in your example. When there where more intensive queries I would see a timeout error. Going back to my setup decided to experiment by closing the driver in some more expensive queries and it looks like (still need more testing) the crashes are gone.

If you are deploying a real-world application I would urge you to think about Authentication and Authorization when using a DB-React setup only as you would have to store username/password of the neo4j server in the client. I am looking into options of having the Neo4J server issuing a token and receiving it for Authorization but the best practice is for sure to have a Node.js server in the middle with something like Passport to handle Authentication.

So, all in all, maybe the best scenario is to only use the driver in Node and have the browser always communicating with the Node server using axios...